# Python. В строке после каждого знака окончания предложения начать часть оставшейся сроки с большой буквы. Как?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет.
Есть такая задачка, помогите пожалуйста решить, реально столько времени убил на нее...

Клиент вводит текст маленькими буквами:
*добрый день. меня зовут вася пупкин. когда вы открываетесь?*

```
  def main():
    
    string = input('Введите предложение: ')
    
    print(modify(string))
    
def modify(s):
    newstr = s[0].upper() + s[1:s.index('!')+ 2] + s[s.index('!')+ 2].upper() \
             + s[s.index('!')+ 3:s.index('?')+ 2] + s[s.index('?')+ 2].upper() \
             + s[s.index('?')+ 3:]
    return newstr
        
main()
```

и результат решения должен быть таким, что первые буквы начала предложения и имени должны быть большими:
*Добрый день. Меня зовут Вася Пупкин. Когда вы открываетесь?*

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Конечно поможем решить, предоставьте ваш вариант решения, для этого нажмите [edit] под вашим вопросом

Comment: @Dmitry, почему-то здесь огромное количество просьб о помощи с указанием, что автор потратитил очень много времени (или перерыл весь интернет), но вот результаты этого авторы обычно так и не показывают...

Comment: Задачка явно школьно-учебная. Покажите результаты "убитого" вами времени. Хоть какие-то. А иначе выглядит так, что вы хотите "убить" наше время, а вот себе высвободить пару минут на танчики. На этом сайте такого не любят.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере вы почему-то и "вася пупкин" написали как "Вася Пупкин", что противоречит условию задачи. Поэтому эту вашу ошибку игнорируем.  В остальном - задача решается следующим образом:

```
import re
string = "добрый день. меня зовут вася пупкин. когда вы открываетесь? так или не так."
opt=''
for s in re.split(r'(?<=[.!?]) ', string):   
    opt=opt+s.capitalize()+' '
print (opt)
```

Результат:

```
Добрый день. Меня зовут вася пупкин. Когда вы открываетесь? Так или не так.
```

Озадачился вопросом -  а вдруг ТС еще не учил регулярные выражения. Можно-ли переписать это задание исключительно на встроенных функциях Python? Ничего подобного при беглом просмотре в интернет не нашел, поєтому привожу свое решение:

```
string = "добрый день. меня зовут вася пупкин. когда вы открываетесь? так или не так."
lst=list(string)
for i in range (len(string)):
    if i == 0: 
        lst[i]=lst[i].upper()
    else:
        if (i<=len(string)-2)and ((lst[i]=='?' or lst[i]=='.' or lst[i]=='!') and (lst[i+1]==' ')):
            lst[i+2]=lst[i+2].upper()
opt=''.join(lst)
print (opt)
```

Понятно, что скорее всего это решение будет не очень эффективным, но для тренировки алгоритмического мышления мне кажется интересным.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @VadooS  -  вам, как новичку, полезно ознакомиться https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers